# ListView - how to add item to the front of the list

Tags: c#, listview, windows-store-apps

windows8.1 store app project-

I have a ListView which is bound to an ObservableCollection of items in the ViewModel. I add an item to said Collection, and execute a sort method which places the added item at the beginning of the list. The Collection updates, but the ListView places the item in the end (right most end basically).

Since the app's requirement is to show the items from left to right (in order of date), I'm in a bind :/

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is there no insert() method to specify the index?

Comment: Thanks Nick, Insert worked perfectly. Strange that the sort didnt reflect all the way through to the GUI /shrug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `collection.Insert(0, item);` to insert an item at the beginning of the collection.